# Concatenating To A Verbatim String Literal With Large Volume Of Text Breaking Into New Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-concatenation

how do I concatenate a variable within a verbatim string literal with large volume of text breaking into newlines? I am using a stringbuilder to append all the string variables but

What I intend doing -

```
StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
variable y = something
variable x = @"text"+ y + "
             other text other text";
variable z = @"blablabla";
variable z2 = @"some other text"

sbuilder.Append(x);
sbuilder.Append(z);
sbuilder.Append(z2);

string html = sbuilder.ToString();
```

What I tried -

```
var variable = modelview.something; 
string form = @"a whole lotta text "+variable+ "even more text";
```

I was getting syntax errors

```
Represents text as a series of Unicode characters.To browse the .NET framework source code for this type, see the Reference Source.
Newline in constant
```

Comment: if you have an error, please show your code and provide the message.

Comment: Just like you concatenate a normal string. `string str = @"a" + "b";`

Comment: I actually edited my question because it was different from the one they claim is a duplicate and still got negged and banned. Smh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for.

```
string myVar = "hello";
string form = $@"My String {myVar}";
```

Answer (score 6):

There are couple of ways of doing it.

One is the classical way

```
var variable = modelview.something; 
string form = @"a whole lotta text " + variable + @" even more text";
```

Another way is to use the `$` string interpolation

```
var variable = modelview.something; 
string form = $@"a whole lotta text {variable} even more text";
```

This code is equivalent of

```
var variable = modelview.something; 
string form = string.Format(@"a whole lotta text {0} even more text", variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either by interpolating

```
string from = $@"a whole lotta text {variable} even more text";
```

or by concatenating

```
string from = @"a whole lotta text" + variable + @"even more text";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `string.Concat()`

```
string a = @"a";
string b = @"b";

string.Concat(a, b); // returns "ab"
```